# How to get a the url of an image from id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, magnifier.js

I know it's such a beginner thing. So I have this image in a div with the id thumb.

```
<img id="thumb" src="https://url-to-a-image">
```

And this Javascript that it's a magnify script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myImgSrc = document.getElementById("thumb").getElementsByTagName("img") 
[0].src;
    var evt = new Event(),
    m = new Magnifier(evt);
    m.attach({
        thumb: '#thumb',
        large: 'myImgSrc',
        largeWrapper: 'preview'
    });
</script>
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the image using myImgSrc and then I'm trying to use in the large: 'myImgSrc'. When I put the a fixed url in large: fixed-url-to-the-image, it works fine.

Comment: Try like this, `var thumb = document.getElementById("thumb").src;` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element with `#thumb` id is the tag `img` it self, the current selector will not return the `src` value, so it should be simply:

```
var myImgSrc = document.getElementById("thumb").src;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get image `src` like this,

```
var thumb = document.getElementById("thumb").src;
```

You don't need to use `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let img = document.querySelector('#thumb');
console.log(img.src);
```

If you use img.src, you'll see the source of your img tag.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` is superfluous - you already have the exact element you want - you selected it by its ID. You'd only need `getElementsByTagName` if you wanted to get one or more elements by their tag and work on them all, rather than identifying one precisely.

So actually the solution is very simple - just get the `src` attribute of the ID-selected element directly. Working demo:

```js
var myImgSrc = document.getElementById("thumb").src;
console.log(myImgSrc);
```

```html
<img id="thumb" src="https://url-to-a-image">
```